# How to get date in C#, without localisation

Tags: c#, mysql, date, localization

My C# application have to read some date from MySQL database. Problem I have is that format of date depends on system localisation settings.

My question is if is possible that I always get date in formats yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss, and yyyy-MM-dd, no matter of localisation settings.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the data type of the column representing the date in MySQL?

Comment: date and datetime (i use them both in several different fields)

Comment: Could you provide a code example where you demonstrate what you're talking about? I'm not sure if you're talking about communication with MySQL or once you have the datetime read from the database and want to present it to the user.

Comment: Is the problem that the value you get _from_ the database varies by locale? Then the problem is not really in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are storing the dates as true date or datetime values, your application will get the raw binary data back, and it will not be subject to localization until you create a string representation of the date values. My guess is that you are looking at the values in the debugger or using `Console.WriteLine(theValue);`, which will use the current locale. Always include the desired format and/or the desired culture when converting non-string values to strings.

If you are storing the dates as strings, you will always have to know exactly what format went into the database.

Assuming the dates are stored as `date` or `datetime`: just handle the values as they are, and don't convert them to strings until you need to show them to a user:

```
DateTime theValue = theReader.GetDateTime(fieldOrdinal);
var theValueAsText = theValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var specificTextRepr = theValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

The `theValueAsText` variable will be a string representation that is not tied to a specific culture. The `specificTextRepr` will be your specific text representation.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be reading it back as a *string* from the database - you haven't shown how you're reading the data, but if you use something to populate a `DataTable`, or LINQ, or `IDataReader.GetDateTime` then there's no string formatting involved (assuming it's stored properly in the database, which it looks like it is).

A `DateTime` value doesn't intrinsically *have* a format, any more than an `int` is in decimal or hex - it's how you *choose* to convert it that matters, and you should almost always avoid doing that formatting unless you really need to.

Answer (score 2):

Since you store the dates in date and date/time specific representations, formatting does not play into it at all (as opposed to some highly discouraged storage schemes when date/time is stored as strings, when formatting does matter, but for a wrong reason).

When you query MySQL from your C# code, you will get the correct dates no matter what your locale is. They will be *displayed* differently based on the locale, but they will *represent* the proper date regardless of the locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date directly in the query by using

`date_format(dob,'%d/%m/%Y')`

```
select date_format(dob,'%d/%m/%Y') dob from student where Id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM d, yyyy");
CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

TO

```
 CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM d, yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```